# HTML Question - Need odd table columns highlighted only

Tags: html, css

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #3399CC;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td { padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #3399CC;
}
th { padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #3399CC;
}
td { text-align: center;
}
.text { text-align: left; 
}
td:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #F5FAFC; }
```

```html
<div id="special">
        <h3>Yurt Packages</h3>
        <p>A variety of luxury yurt packages are available. Choose a package below and contact us to begin your reservation. We’re happy to build a custom package just for you!</p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Package Name</th>
      <th class="text">Description</th>
      <th>Nights</th>
      <th>Cost per Person</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
     <td>Weekend Escape</td>
     <td class="text">Two breakfasts, a trail map, and a picnic snack</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>$450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Zen Retreat</td>
     <td class="text">Four breakfasts, a trail map, a picnic snack, and a pass for the daily sunrise Yoga session</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>$600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kayak Away</td>
     <td class="text">Two breakfasts, two hours of kayak rental daily, and a trail map</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>$500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

What you see here is HTML and CSS code for a table, that is supposed to be white and blue.

INSTRUCTIONS ask that the ODD columns are BLUE, but instead everything has a blue background. I cannot figure it out :(
help appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: posting pictures of your code is really inconsiderate.  If you want help post your actual code

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71542374/edit) to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are having.

Comment: The 1st and 3rd columns are blue. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is CSS that will get the job done at the table cell level. If you don't want the table header to have the blue and white colors, just remove the `th` selectors from the CSS.

```css
th:nth-child(even), td:nth-child(even) {
  background: white;
  }
th:nth-child(odd), td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
  }
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Package Name</th>
  <th class="text">Description</th>
  <th>Nights</th>
  <th>Cost per Person</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
  <td>This is stesg</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css add

```
tr:nth-child(odd){
   backgound-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below. If you want the table header in a different color then you are nesting **thead tr** selectors and setting the background color from the CSS.

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead tr {
  background-color: #140c12;
  color: #fff;
}
th {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
}
td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
  text-align: center;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eb7d4b;
}
.text {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="special">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Package Name</th>
      <th class="text">Description</th>
      <th>Nights</th>
      <th>Cost per Person</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Weekend Escape</td>
        <td class="text">
          Two breakfasts, a trail map, and a picnic snack
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zen Retreat</td>
        <td class="text">
          Four breakfasts, a trail map, a picnic snack, and a pass for the
          daily sunrise Yoga session
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>$600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kayak Away</td>
        <td class="text">
          Two breakfasts, two hours of kayak rental daily, and a trail map
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kayak Away</td>
        <td class="text">
          Two breakfasts, two hours of kayak rental daily, and a trail map
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>$800</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```